# Server side programming: simple tutorial for getting started with server/client

Tags: google-app-engine

I apologize in advance for the open-ended question.  I tried searching, but wasn't sure what specifically to search for, in all honesty...

Briefly put, I'm a novice iPhone programmer and I've made applications that have communicated with a Java server.  For example, my iphone application would use HTTP Get or POST requests and would receive back data.  However, I'm not the person writing the server side code and frankly, have no idea how it's done!

I'd like to learn at least the mechanics of how things are done on both sides, so now I'm trying to learn.  I picked up a book on Google App Engine since it seems like an economical way just in case I do decide to release a server/client app.

However, I assume that I could have chosen RoR or PHP as well.  I'm assuming the principles must be the same.

If anyone could point me towards tutorials that shows the "other side" of what happens in a server/client app, that would be most appreciated!  By other side, I mean, on the client side, I already know how to request and receive data.  I just dont know what happens on the server side...

Thank you and sorry for the general question..

Comment: So many great answers, I wish I could check them all.  Thank you all for the great answers!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are most important components of web application:

- an http server: serves static files, works as a pipe to your applplication for dynamic content. For example: apache, nginx.
- An actual web application: handles requests for dynamic content. Usually you use a a web-framework. For example: django for python, symfony for php, RoR for Ruby, node.js for javascript.
- A database server. For example: MySQL, PostgreSQL

Some other things which might be considered:

- a mail server to send email messages
- image processing libraries
- fulltext search engines

These components are less common:

- memory caching server, for example: memcache
- non relational databases, for example: redis, couchdb, riak, mongodb
- task queue server: for example RabbitMQ

The reason why appengine might seem easier for novice is that you don't need to configure web server or database. You only need to write your application code. Fully-managed hosting with task queue, memcache, datastore, content-delivery-network are already available in appengine.

The problem with appengine is that it forces many limitations on you.

If you don't need memcache, task queue and distributed system then it is very easy to develop applications with popular frameworks, they provide tutorials how to set up your own http server and database.

If you need these advanced parts then it will be more difficult to configure everything.

Common practices in web application development include:

- using ORM to work with relational database
- using MVC or similar pattern to structure code
- Html code is kept away from code in templates. Thus templating language is used.

As a web-backend developer aside from coding application code you also need to understand well the database which you use.

If you only build a backend for your mobile application, you won't need HTML, CSS, Javascript and templating. Though MVC pattern and ORM still applies. You also will need to know more about HTTP protocol and various methods of implementing an HTTP API. If you like XML, the WSDL does a good job. There are great libraries for WSDL which makes writing HTTP API easy.

Answer (score 1):

The base API in Java is the Servlet API. Read [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnafd.html).

On top of this API, there exist a myriad of frameworks (Stripes, Spring MVC, Struts2, JSF, Wicket, etc.), which all have their own philosophy. There are two groups of frameworks, though: action-based ones (Stripes, Spring MVC, Struts2, ...) and component-based ones (JSP, Wicket, ...).

The action-based ones usually use JSPs for their view technology (to generate the markup), but also support others. What you'll learn if you learn JSP will be useful in a variety of frameworks, so I would learn it as well. Read [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnagx.html).

Answer (score 0):

I think, starting from app engine may not be good idea for starter for server side developing.

Asp.net ( or php) will be more "efficient": not only source for learning and tutorials but also better for make mistakes and learn better

Once you done with asp.net, and have good pratice about your server side project,
it is easy and very fast move to app engine

good luck

Comment: If you make a mistake on appengine you have to pay money. For example if you did a mistake while structuring your data and you found the mistake when you have 1 million records in your database it can cost over 100$ to restructure the database.

Comment: What abaout Node.js?

Answer (score 0):

I applaud your choice of starting with App Engine:

1. Some concepts of GAE are hard, but so is SQL. If you don't know either you might just start with GAE which is a modern noSql system.
2. GAE is not a good fit for all problems. But I believe it is a good fit for your setup: a lot of independent clients with limited need for heavy queries.
3. About the cost: GAE is cheap if you know how to programm it. I have both EC2 and GAE in different setups, and while they are hard to compare, I believe GAE is cheaper.
4. IMHO most of the cost of hosting comes from support/management cost. We have a team 10+ developers, but no system/database admin.